# Internet Connects, but only works sporadically

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my HP Chromebook 14. Unfortunately, I've been having some networking problems.

When I connect to the Internet, one of two things happen. Occasionally, the Internet works well. However, more often than not, I get page not loading error. No internet functions, yet I can access the router and local networks (Minecraft LAN worlds for one thing). I've tried with several different networks, some with better results than others. Anything I can try? Or additional information I can provide? Thanks in advance.
Contents of wireless-info.txt (thanks wild-man):

[**Contents of wireless-info.txt**](http://textuploader.com/mqim)

Comment: If this is the wifi please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-
what-can-i-do>

Comment: I post an answer, did you run those commands one at a time, it was very hard to read and some info did not come out, if it does not work run the script again and post the results.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwldvm
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

Copy and paste for accuracy and
Watch for errors.

Also check the security encryption settings in both the computer wireless profile and the router. For home use we recommend WPA2-AES and avoid options related to TKIP.

Set IPV6 to ignore in network manager.